# Are there any +1 Level Adjustment templates that grant Damage Reduction?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation

I'm looking for a template with no more than a +1 LA that grants Damage Reduction. If possible it would be best if it applied to Humanoids but I can also make Monstrous Humanoid or Giant work. I am aware of Mineral Warrior, but it doesn't serve my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Unseelie Fey, a +0 LA template grants DR based on your HD, but also extra damage against you from enemies using iron weaponry.

There are a **bunch** of templates that are "LA —" (i.e. Not For Players) that grant DR, amongst other things.

[Here is a list of all the D&D 3.5e templates.](http://community.wizards.com/forum/previous-editions-character-optimization/threads/1117261)

Answer (score 0):

Half-Fey is +1 LA and gives DR 5/cold iron. It can be applied to any living corporeal creature.

The Half Shadow and Half Dragon have damage reduction too.

Comment: The file you linked to was [removed from Crystal Keep at the request of WotC](http://www.crystalkeep.com/d20/). I don't think we should be copying text from it here, so I've removed the details and left an overview of the relevant features.

Comment: Half-Fey is LA+2 but I found Unseelie Fey out of Dragon Magazine #304 which grants scaling DR based on hit dice. Thanks for the help guys.